# call inner function from global function to display alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code and want to extend this code now. how can I write a makeAMessenger function in global scope so that it triggers when user clicks document and alert below message

```
THIS. IS. SPART.
```

currently I have following code.

[CODE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/heBCH/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean ***[this](http://jsfiddle.net/heBCH/3/)*** ?

```
function makeAMessenger(madness, sparta) {
   return madness.bind(sparta);
}
```

Comment: For this i get `unexpected token ILLEGAL` in console

Comment: @al0neevenings What browser are you using?

Comment: But it does not alert that message which I want. any reason?

Comment: @al0neevenings Are you using the newest version of chrome?

Comment: yes I am. But somehow when I mixed your and @alliswell solution together then it works

Comment: @al0neevenings Have you checked the link of my answer?

Comment: yes it i working thanks. I dont know why it didnt work at first.

Answer (score 1):

have a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uJsZC/)  and you don't need to pass variable along, it can be accessed in function.

```
      function makeAMessenger(madness) {
        return madness;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function#apply()` or `Function#call()` to bind `this`.
http://jsfiddle.net/QfNbp/